# UIPageController and Slide Menu

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Такая проблема: использую UIPageController как mainView subview. UIPageController имеет две страницы. Когда нахожусь на первой странице при слайде с лева на право надо открывать slide menu, но из-за UIPageController, сролится UIPageController, но меню не открывается. Сделал так, что добавил UISwipeGestureRecognizer и action открываю меню, но это выглядит очень плохо, меню открывается резко, и сразу до конца, т.е. как при нажатии кнопки, а нужно чтобы можно было открывать плавно (следует за swipe). Возможно ли как-то это исправить?

Вот мой код:

```
 UISwipeGestureRecognizer *leftRecognizer;
        leftRecognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipeRight:)];
        [leftRecognizer setDirection: UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight];
        leftRecognizer.delegate = self;
        [_pageViewController.view addGestureRecognizer:leftRecognizer];

- (void) handleSwipeRight: (UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)sender {
    if (_currentIndex == 0)
    {
        [[SlideNavigationController sharedInstance] openMenu:MenuLeft withCompletion:nil];
    }
}
```

Comment: Замените на `UIPanGestureRecognizer` и следите за изменением `velocityInView`. либо сделайте свой класс, наследованный от `UIPageController` и в нем наприямую смотрите `touchesMoved`

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko Можете пояснить, как пользоваться velocityInView?

Comment: смотрите `[sender velocityInView:_pageViewController.view].x;` это будет относительно оси x. И от этого уже открывайте свой слайд. помните, что velocity это не то же самое, что touchesMoved - полного совпадения между движением пальца и velocity вы не добьетесь. можете делить результат  на 10, чтобы получалось плавнее.

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko не как не могу понять, я использую https://github.com/aryaxt/iOS-Slide-Menu, там есть функция `openMenu: withCompletion:` но она открывает меню резко, если делаю свай по self.view, тогда все хорошо, но с pageViewController, так и не могу разобраться.

Answer (score 1):

Вот такой хак придумал.

У вас есть два `UIPanGestureRecognizer`:

- один в `UIPageViewController` - его если надо, можно выудить через `self.pageController.gestureRecognizers[0];`. Ему нельзя менять `delegate`, так что если вам надо будет что то с ним делать, то придется делать сабкласс `UIPageViewController` и задавать его `<UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>`.
- второй в `SlideNavigationController.m`, называется `@property (nonatomic, strong) UIPanGestureRecognizer *panRecognizer;`. Может его придется вынести в `.h`, чтобы сделать public.

Сначала надо через делегат объявить, что оба рекогнайзера могут обрабатываться одновременно. Для этого возвращать `YES` в `-gestureRecognizer: shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:`.

После этого надо надо для рекогнайзера из slideMenu настроить правила - он должен обрабатываться только, если вы находитесь на первой странице своего `UIPageViewController` и если движение пальцем началось вправо `index == 0 && [panRecognizer velocityInView:someView] > 0`. Для этого использовать метод делегата `-gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:`.

Что надо помнить:

- Как я уже сказал, для рекогнайзера в `UIPageViewController` нельзя переопределять делегат - там какие то приватные эпловские методы вызываются. Можно сделать сабкласс и в нем уже написать все нужные методы делегата.
- рекогнайзер в `slideMenu` тоже вызывает как минимум один метод делегата, так что надо либо дописывать свои методы в том же классе, либо переопределять делегат, но иметь ввиду, что надо будет и оригинальный метод вызывать в своем методе.
- во всем этом шабаше есть еще два рекогнайзера, которые могут вам попасться под руку - по одному в каждом классе. Они оба `UITapGestureRecognizer`. Просто помните, во всех методах делегата проверять Pan/Tap и обрабатывать только Pan.
- возможно вам придется добавлять рекогнайзер от `slideMenu` к другому вью, не уверен.